# How to disable MongoDB cache for specific collection?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm running a MongoDB service and some of the collections are data store only and I don't want let MongoDB loads these collections' data into memory. Is there any configuration for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not load the collection into memory, only the collection's indexes.

By default index is _id field only. You can't remove the _id index.